# Python Shapely - find if parts of two multi polygons overlap

Tags: python, shapely

From the Shapely documentation - is there any function that can let me know that the red multipolygon on the right overlaps some parts of the yellow multiplolygon on the right? 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Good to know:**

You can apply the same "Predicates and Relationships" methods on MultiPolygons that you can apply on any other Geometric Object in shapely ([see documentation](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#predicates-and-relationships)).

**Check for overlapping:**

To check if two Multipolygons overlap you can use `object.intersects(other)`. See this example (not the MultiPolygons from your picture though):

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon
a = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0)]
b = [(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 1), (1, 1)]

multi1 = MultiPolygon([[a, []], [b, []]])

c = [(0, 1.5), (1.5, 1.5), (1.5, 3), (0, 3), (1.5, 3)]
d = [(1.5, 1.5), (1.5, 0), (3, 0), (3, 1.5), (1.5, 1.5)]

multi2 = MultiPolygon([[c, []], [d, []]])

print(multi1.intersects(multi2))
print(multi2.intersects(multi1))
```

Returns

```
>>>True
>>>True
```

**Edit:**

Apparently, OP is not interested in overlapping, but is "trying to find out if the red [multi]polygon has the exact same coordinates as parts of the yellow one".

In that case you can iterate over the individual Polygons and check if they are equal to one of the target Polygons:

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon
#target multipolygon
a = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0)]
b = [(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 1), (1, 1)]
c = [(2, 1), (3, 1), (3, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
multi_target = MultiPolygon([[a, []], [b, []], [c, []]])

#test multipolygon with two polygons that match a target polygon
a = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0)]
b = [(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 1), (1, 1)]
multi_test1 = MultiPolygon([[a, []], [b, []]])

#test multipolygon where one polygon does not exactly match a target polygon.
a = [(0, 0.5), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0.5), (0, 0.5)]
b = [(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 1), (1, 1)]
multi_test2 = MultiPolygon([[a, []], [b, []]])

def check_multipolys(test, target):
    for test_poly in test:
        exists = False
        for target_poly in target:
            if test_poly.equals(target_poly):
                exists = True
                break
        if not exists:
            return False
    return True

>>>check_multipolys(multi_test1, multi_target)
>>>True
>>>check_multipolys(multi_test2, multi_target)
>>>False
```

For the future: the source code would have been more helpful to answer your question, than a screenshot of the documentation.

Comment: Thanks - though this is not really what I was looking for. 
I am actually trying to find out if the  red polygon has the exact same coordinates as parts of the  yellow one.

Comment: @Yair but it is what you were asking for;) see my edit for an answer to your problem. I left the overlapping part in case people searching for the overlapping of multipolygons come here.